# Is there a hosted version of Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn

Is there a hosted version of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? Something similar to the hosted version of jQuery on Google?

Comment: If you guys are interested in Google CDN support for bootstrap, please add your +1 starring the issue on google-ajax-apis bug tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=637 - Thanks.

Comment: <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> This question was helpful for me.

Comment: <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> This if in <head> for css. Thx Mr. Strang for the question.

Comment: Yes, you can load it from [bootstrap cdn](https://pagecdn.com/lib/bootstrap).

Answer (score 169, accepted):

### [BootstrapCDN.com](http://bootstrapcdn.com)

Hosts the Javascript, CSS, and Image files.

Additionally hosts the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) CSS and a selection of [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) themes.

Maintained by [@jdorfman](http://twitter.com/jdorfman) and [@mervinej](https://twitter.com/mervinej).

---

### [CDNJS.com](http://www.cdnjs.com)

Hosts the JavaScript, CSS and Image files. Check the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap) for more specifics.

Also hosts a ton of other JS libraries, including plenty of Bootstrap plugins/addons.

Maintained by [@peterdavehello](https://twitter.com/peterdavehello).

Comment: BootstrapCDN.com  has the JS files, CSS Files, + SSL Support.

Comment: The vanilla deployment is the best way to use bootstrap.  Put your own customization in a separate file.   That way you can take advantage of CDN / Local caching.

Comment: @Frank - The notion that vanilla is "the best way" is a rather strong assertion.  In fact, the way in which the official [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html) page encourages using LESS to generate customized CSS tends to imply that consolidating to a single custom file is the recommended practice.

Comment: The problem with relying on less is that first you cannot use a shared cdn, because everyone will have their own changes, and 2nd its not so easy to update bootstrap changes without recompiling from less, or unless you have code that does that for you.   

It would be nice if bootstrap's less generator, simply only created a bootstrap-custom.css file that could be used in conjunction with the bootstrap framework.  Truly separate style from style :)

Comment: cdnjs now has full support for css and image hosting - https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0

Comment: @RyanKirkman Alright, I'll update the answer! Thanks for the official confirmation. :D

Answer (score 7):

This is a common request: [Direct download links (or CDN)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1679) Also looks like the library not on any CDN at the moment.

You could use the raw github files, although this is not good practise, see: [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries)

Comment: Is there a way to ask google to add this to their CDN?

Comment: @ChristianStrang yes, star the issue on Google bugtracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=637