# Twitter Bootstrap online loader?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosted version of Twitter Bootstrap (maybe Google?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887867/hosted-version-of-twitter-bootstrap-maybe-google)

I want to know if exists some site that provides the Twiiter Bootstrap framework for online loading instead of using it in my website, so this can save bandwidth from my host.

There is something similar provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) to Javascript libraries, but for Bootstrap, I found nothing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I guess you could link to github, but I doubt this is a CDN.

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, it is uncompressed.

**Update:** The javascript part is available on [cdnjs.cloudflare.com](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.2/bootstrap.min.js).

Relevant discussion here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1679

**UPDATE**:
NetDNA has set up a project site on their CDN just for Twitter Bootstrap.  Its called http://Bootstrapcdn.com.  Supports SSL.  Has the CSS Files.

Answer (score 11):

[BootstrapCDN.com](http://BootstrapCDN.com)  has the css files, and ssl support.   On a real CDN with nodes all over the world.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you are looking for is a CDN (Content Delivery Network), I don't know of any CDN that currently host the twitter bootstrap css/jscript. Another suggestion would be to use Amazon's AWS service more specifically the CloudFront service:

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/