# Is it possible to host twitter bootstrap.css in google just like jquery?

Tags: css, api, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, google-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosted version of Twitter Bootstrap (maybe Google?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887867/hosted-version-of-twitter-bootstrap-maybe-google)

As of now I'm loading my jquery [from google](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js) like this.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Twitter Bootstrap is the [most popular project](https://github.com/popular/watched) in github. I think its getting popular day by day and I'm pretty sure bootstrap used by many sites.

If there is a centralised api to load bootstrap, the page will obviously load faster because it could potentially already be cached in client's browser just like jQuery.

Something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bootstrap.twitter.com/2.2.2/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//bootstrap.twitter.com/2.2.2/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Already talked about this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887867/hosted-version-of-twitter-bootstrap-maybe-google

Comment: Not really a programming question and you'd have found this with one easy combination of 'bootstrap' and 'cdn' with the quite well known google search engine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hate to give such a simple answer but:

http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Comment: Also https://cdnjs.com/