# What is the BootstrapCDN link to the NON-responsive version of Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Does anybody know what the link of the NON-responsive version of Bootstrap is on BootstrapCDN?  It is not published on the main page.

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9887867/1485952

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the other question addresses the general Bootstrap CDN. This is about where the NON-responsive (which is not published on the websites) version is.

Comment: @fnkr No, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: lol just because you edited your post: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17470566/revisions - At the time I wrote my comment it was a duplicate...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[BootstrapCDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) does not post it on the main page, but after searching a little I found [this issue](https://github.com/netdna/bootstrap-cdn/issues/50) in their Git repo where you can find the link:

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.no-responsive.no-icons.min.css
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's one without responsiveness, but with icons?

Comment: Are you referring to Bootstrap 2 or 3? 3 is always responsive. I cannot find the version 2 on `bootstrapcdn.com` anymore on the website. (the old links still work)

Comment: I ended up looking through the source of bootstrapcdn on Github, concluding that it wasn't there and using a 'customised' version from the Bootstrap site. I guess for a high-usage site it would be advisable to rely on the CDN and then override unwanted styles..

Comment: @Joost There doesn't appear to be for 2.3.2, but it looks like `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` is what you're looking for if 2.3.1 is sufficient.

Comment: Additional note for those using this, http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/ is now the officially supported domain -- over netdna.bootstrapcdn.com.