# Bootstrap referencing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I have followed the tutorials on codeacademy and I am experimenting with getting to grips writing code for a website without tutorial guidance.

I'm not sure how to reference to Bootstrap other than the way that is given on the online tutorials which is using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Do you reference Bootstrap from your own computer after downloading the files?
Or do you reference an online source such as the one above?

Comment: You can use [CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) for bootstrap or you can add files in your folder and link it.

Answer (score 3):

Embedding Bootstrap can be done in two ways. You can either host a copy on your own server or use a copy from a CDN. Both ways have their advantages and disadvantages. It's up to you which way you prefer.

**Local copy**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

**CDN**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The [Gettings started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page will explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

[BootstrapCDN.com](http://bootstrapcdn.com)

Hosts the Javascript, CSS, and Image files. Also has SSL support.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This question is already answered here: [Is there a hosted version of Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887867/hosted-version-of-twitter-bootstrap-maybe-google)

Answer (score 0):

Danny, if you downloaded the files, you don't need to refer it. You can just call the file in the page.
or other solution is , you don't need to download files, you can refer Bootstrap CDN link from this page http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

cheers!