# Why google maps doesn't work with gmaps.js + ie9?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9, google-maps-markers

I don't underestand why the google maps complement works with ie8, firefox, chrome and safari, but crashes with ie9... I used [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/) library for google maps. I tried to desactivate the modernizr complement, or bootstrap, but still not working...

http://masqmenos.com/eng/donde-quedamos.php

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me a look into the console is sufficient to answer this question(you should also sometimes take a look into the console).

IE has blocked the script https://raw.github.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js because of wrong MIME-type(it is served as "text/plain").

GitHub is not a CDN, copy the file onto your Server.

See: [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm nooby... I will look the console next time, and I'm not going to use gh like a cdn...