# Get stylesheet for WordPress theme from GitHub

Tags: wordpress, github

I'm wondering if it's possible to serve a stylesheet from a GitHub account into WordPress so that any changes made to the GitHub file are automatically served?

If so, can someone please explain or point me in the right direction to accomplishing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you might get in trouble. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5503156/538866) answer. Basically Github will serve your files as "raw" files. The browsers must then depend on the `type` parameter, which may or may not work as it should.

Github also has a bandwidth limit so if you have a lot of visitors they might cut down on your bandwidth usage (i. e. block access to the stylesheet).

There are other problems, as outlined in the linked post. For example the lack of caching which means your visitors have to download the stylesheet every visit they make.

Comment: Thanks Jonas I might see if I can ask a more general question to see if there are any solutions to my problem. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yeah, if you're asking about automatic deployment, I am sure a bunch of people will let you in on their methods. Good luck!