# How do I fill a ko.observerablearray from a rest call based on user input (jsfiddle includer)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm new to Knokout. How can I fill an observable array in my view model when a user clicks a button. The object from the server will be large , so I want to use ko.mapping to make them observables.

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/russellgove/UXbnz/

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UXbnz/5/**

Use `ko.mapping.fromJS(FrimServer, {}, this.trades);` to update your observableArray with the new data from the server.

I've also taken the liberty to clean up your fiddle a bit.

1. Use `var self = this` is common practice when defining your ViewModel in JavaScript. This to avoid problems with closure and scope.
2. Replaced `<label>` elements with `<span>` elements. `<label>` is meant specifically for assigning labels to input elements.
3. Moved references to Knockout files to Managed Resources. This is the appropriate way to reference external libraries in a jsFiddle
4. Added some styling and extra elements for clarity.
5. Expanded data and displaying of data to showcase possible scenario's.

Comment: Wow,Thanks for all the help. I went to you modified fiddle, but when I click the gettrades button, it still diesnt display the trade data. Is there somthing I'm missing?

Comment: That's weird. It works fine in my browser (Google Chrome). What browser are you using? do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: OK, I'm using IE8. I dont see any js errors. Let me try it in chrome.

Comment: Correction: I was using Ie9 on my personal laptop and do not see the trades. On my work computer running ie8, it works. Does knowkout really work cross-browser, or is this type of issue common?

Comment: It's a common issue that actually has nothing to do with your code. The problem is that we're pulling knockout and mapping from `raw.github.com`. GitHub is not a content delivery network and has several catches when you reference files directly from its servers. For one, in IE9 you will see the following error: `SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/master/build/output/knockout-latest.debug.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch`. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries

Comment: hey, thanks for your help.  setting the self=this was definitely part of the problem. The other main issue I had was that my knockout code was running in sharepoint. When sharepoint saw the  div tag with the data-bind attribute, it didn't send it to the browser (a sharepoint 'quirk;). Once I put the template in a <script> tag, sharepoint did send it to the browser, so the template could be used. If anyone else is using Knockoot with Sharepoint.... the 'containerless templates' may not work. you may need to pt the templates in a script tag.