# Knockout mapping is broken in jsFiddle

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, jsfiddle

Why isn't this fiddle working?

Error:

Line: 42
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'fromJS': object is null or undefined

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rboarman/YWPjT/)

I noticed that a bunch of other ko.mapping examples in jsFiddle are also broken. I included the js file as a resource.

[image]

Comment: In which browser?  Your fiddle seems to work for me in Firefox 15.0.1 and Chrome 21.0.1180.89

Comment: Good question, IE9, I'll try FF

Comment: Confirmed, broken in IE9

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with referencing resources from `raw.github.com`. GitHub is **not** a Content Delivery Network and is not meant to be used as such.

See this related question for more information: [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries)