# Github GraphQL API: how to get rep's one source file by GrahpQL api?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

Github GraphQL API:  how to get rep's one source file by GrahpQL api ?

For example, if there's a data file like  `somedata.json`, is there a way to fetch it by  Github GraphQL API ?

Comment: I find the answer at [html-automatically-fetching-json-file-from-github-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403218/html-automatically-fetching-json-file-from-github-repo)

Answer (score -1):

So the answer would be

1. get the files path in the folder by:

> [GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:tree_sha](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/)

2. get the file by `raw.githubusercontent.com/`

> [html-automatically-fetching-json-file-from-github-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403218/html-automatically-fetching-json-file-from-github-repo)