# How to reference code off github?

Tags: html, github, cdn

I want to use this Javascript from Github:
https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/src/jquery.csv.min.js

I didn't want to work out some wacky solution when I know there is probably a simple way to do this.

So I am hoping there is a way I can reference this in a `<script src= ??? ></script>` in my html, just like I would reference anything off Google CDN.

Comment: download it and reference it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries)

Answer (score 4):

You don't. GitHub is *not* a CDN. Do not (try to) use it as such. Download the file and use it locally.

Comment: Are you telling me that if I do work out a hacky solution github is going to blacklist all my users? I don't think so.

Comment: Here's a related (albiet closed) question that goes more into *why* this is a bad idea, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries

Comment: And as to your question, @kpie: as per [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox), the answer is yes, GitHub actively tries to block your ability to do this because it is a bad idea and should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, but you can try [RawGit](http://rawgit.com/).