# Issue in referencing external js file inside html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reference external js file inside my html as follow, did I miss something? The pie chart is supposed to appear but I am not getting it.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_src

```html
<script src="http://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.js"></script>
<script src="http://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.min.js"></script>

<div><span class="pie">1/5</span></div>
```

Comment: Open console and read the message explaining it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has 4 main problems:

1. You didn't call jQuery inside the HTML document `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, that *must* be called before the plugin
2. You called twice the plugin: both the minified and not minified version (if available, always request for the minified version since it's lighter)
3. You requested the plugin over `HTTP` instead the always better `HTTPS`
4. You didn't call the function inside the document with `$(".pie").peity("pie")`

Here's a working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
  <span class="pie">1/5</span>
  <span class="pie">226/360</span>
  <span class="pie">0.52/1.561</span>
  <span class="pie">1,4</span>
  <span class="pie">226,134</span>
  <span class="pie">0.52,1.041</span>
  <span class="pie">1,2,3,2,2</span>
</div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".pie").peity("pie");
    });  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have missed the JavaScript snippet
1. Loading order Should be changed ,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.pie").peity("pie");
  });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div><span class="pie">1/5</span>
<span class="pie">226/360</span>
<span class="pie">0.52/1.561</span>
<span class="pie">1,4</span>
<span class="pie">226,134</span>
<span class="pie">0.52,1.041</span>
<span class="pie">1,2,3,2,2</span></div>
 <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three changes to be made in your code.

1. You need to include jQuery.
2. You need to call the `peity()` function on the `span`.
3. You need not include both `jquery.peity.js` and `jquery.peity.min.js`. Including either one is sufficient.

See code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.pie").peity("pie");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.min.js"></script>

<div><span class="pie">1/5</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for highlight my mistakes. But I'm still not getting the result.

Comment: Are you able to run the above snippet and get the result?

Comment: yup. I can Run code snippet here. But my dojo is not working yet.

Comment: He doesn't actually *need to call the peity() function on the span*, `$(".pie").peity("pie")` is enough

Comment: @NewBie Can you please edit your question and paste your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, your Dojo snippet isn't working because you're trying to load the Peity plugin over HTTP from a page being served over HTTPS. [Your](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) [web](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) [console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console) will tell you that the browser blocks loading [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) from an HTTPS page.

Load `peity.js` from `https://benpickles.github.io/peity/jquery.peity.js`. But when you publish your site, download `peity.min.js` and host it on your own server. [Github is not a CDN.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries)

Comment: Good to know! I will take note on that. But my piety ,alone, is working now finally http://dojo.telerik.com/uTikoB, here I am not getting js reference from Github, instead directly referencing from their hosting site http://benpickles.github.io/peity/.