# Javascript fetch giving CORS error despite using GH pages and CORS Proxies

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, github-pages, liveserver

I am working on a virtual piano application, and I'm having a lot of issues with trying to fetch audio files from github. Specifically, I keep getting the errors

> Access to fetch at `'https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3'` from origin `'http://127.0.0.1:5500'` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
GET https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
@ piano.js:57 ready  

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at createAudioBuffers (piano.js:57:26) at ready (piano.js:28:26) at piano.js:13:5
```

In my code, I am simply calling fetch via

```js
const c4AudioURL = "https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3";   
const c4AudioFetch = fetch(c4AudioURL);
```

I am using Live Server on VSCode, so I tried to deploy my site to GH Pages to see if that would fix things, but I still got the errors. I also tried two different CORS proxies, one being crossorigin.me and my code changing to

```js
const c4AudioURL = "https://crossorigin.me/https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3";
```

and the other changing my code to

```js
const c4AudioURL = "https://corsproxy.io/https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp";
```

Am I missing something here? I suppose It's that possible that I'm missing something in my code or in the way I'm using Github, as I'm a pretty inexperience programmer. I've been stuck on this for a while, so I appreciate any ideas you might have!

Comment: `After trying two different CORS proxies` where? your code is not using a proxy at all

Comment: the simplest solution is to use your own server to proxy the request

Comment: try to configure the package.json script. refering: https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_44877713/article/details/119793688 or https://blog.csdn.net/liangzhenAAAAA/article/details/88695498?spm=1001.2101.3001.6650.1&utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7ECTRLIST%7ERate-1-88695498-blog-131572166.235%5Ev40%5Epc_relevant_3m_sort_dl_base3&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2%7Edefault%7ECTRLIST%7ERate-1-88695498-blog-131572166.235%5Ev40%5Epc_relevant_3m_sort_dl_base3&utm_relevant_index=2

Comment: @JaromandaX Added the proxies

Comment: and you have an account with them? By the way, didn't realise the github repo was yours, so it seems bizarre you want to access your own data via github

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah I'm very new with JavaScript so I wasn't really sure of the best way to fetch a file. I was kind of thinking that if I used a local path, the user wouldn't be able to access that? But I suppose if I just included the file locally when I deployed the site, it would have all worked? I think that's what the first answer below is saying, and I'm working on implementing that now to see if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local / server-relative paths. For example, say your directory structure looks like this...

```
.
├── index.html
├── piano.js
└── sounds
    └── c4-virtual-piano.mp3
```

With either LiveServer serving this directory or deploying it to Github Pages, you can fetch assets without going cross-origin

```js
const res = await fetch('sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3');
```

That way it will work wherever you run it, as long as you publish your MP3 files when deploying to Github pages. Then you won't need to worry about CORS at all

Answer (score 0):

The url used for the GET request shown in the post is

```
https://github.com/benvessely/virtual-piano/blob/main/sounds/c4-virtual-piano.mp3
```

returns the same **HTML** github page returned by opening the `sounds` folder in the main repo, and clicking on the "c4-virtual-piano.mp3" link opened up. It is not a link to the mp3 file.

On the "c4-virtual-piano.mp3" HTML page that loads, right click on the button labelled "View raw" and copy the link to the actual mp3 file (or a route to it :-),  which can be copy and pasted into the `src` attribute of an `audio` element to play the sound - a 17 second piano note with attack and decay.

I suggest looking at the possibility of using a public CDN for downloading project files in production: [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5502540/5217142) could be worth a look at, but contains references to some outdated and now unavailable services.