# How do you parse json after importing json2.js?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to Support IE7. In IE10 developers tool  I'm setting "Document mode to IE7 standards" but it still says  "JSON is not defined"
here is my test HTML code:

```
Web site: <span id="wurl"></span><br/>
Title: <span id="wtitle"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://knivesandtools.nl/2011/js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// example of what is received from server
var jsnstr = '{"url": "http://coursesweb.net/", "title": "Web Development Courses", "users": 1500}';

// parse the "jsnstr", and store the JSON object in "obj"
var obj = JSON.parse(jsnstr);

// uses the JavaScript object, adds the values from "url", and "title" in web page
document.getElementById('wurl').innerHTML = obj.url;
document.getElementById('wtitle').innerHTML = obj.title;
</script>
```

Comment: If you support IE 7, you should be testing in real browser. Set up virtual machine or use [modern.IE](http://www.modern.ie/en-us).

Comment: problem is some clients are viewing our pages with IE10,9  but with Document mode  IE7 standards . and they complain about this problem. they are not usinng IE7 actually so I need to check it this way. even <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EdGE" > tag is not helping sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with `JSON.parse(str)`.

However, since you tagged this question with jQuery, you could use `$.parseJSON(str)`.

Double check that json2.js is loaded correctly.

I've pasted a minified version and tried it successfully in ie7:

http://jsfiddle.net/7bmRe/2/show/

Here is the [source](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.min.js), please use this version (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994577/is-there-a-publicly-available-cdn-that-hosts-json2)).

Answer (score -1):

IE7 mode don't support JSON object, if you want to parse json with it you'll need to use some different parser.

I supose that you are importing json2.js to that, you should check it's documentation to see how it's used.

Comment: **Read the question**. The OP's code _clearly_ has a link to `json2.js` in a `<script>` tag